# Can I connect Gamepad for Nexus Player on smartphone?

Tags: bluetooth, game-controllers

With the new gamepad for the Nexus Player that came out earlier this year, can we connect this gamepad to a smartphone like the Nexus 5 to play games or it only connects to the Nexus Player? It uses Bluetooth 3.0, at first sight it should work but maybe it uses a different Bluetooth protocol just like the PS3 controller.

Gamepad for Nexus Player:
https://play.google.com/store/devices/details/Gamepad_for_Nexus_Player?id=nexus_player_gamepad&hl=en

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You put the gamepad into pairing mode by holding down the home button + the back button for 5 seconds, until you see the blue lights flashing, and connecting to the gamepad in the Bluetooth settings in your smartphone.